# Docker swarm replicaion

Tags: docker-swarm

Please, i have a question about Docker Swarm. 
Docker Swarm replicate containers on hosts. What is the type of replication used, state machine (active replication) or passive replication ?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Docker Swarm does not replicate containers. You can set a Swarm service to have X number of "replicas" which will cause it to spin up X containers of that same image, across your servers in the Swarm cluster.

Answer (score 1):

All the production ready containerized environments are characterized by the usage of some orchestrator.

In this case, and specific to Swarm but the same applies to other containers orchestrators, the container is only an end result.

The main management concern are services in Docker Swarm or deployments in Kubernetes, for example.

A service in Swarm defines the configuration manifest for a specific image to be run inside the Swarm cluster. And the replication configuration is one possible parameter of this configuration. In Swarm terminology, a replica is said to be a task.

Finally, the replication model in Docker is very well defined using the X-axis of the Scale Cube Model. [image]